# What does I.T.E stand for when it comes to power supplys?

Tags: power-supply, power

I wish I could give you more but I have a AC adaptor which I am trying to find ( as it's ... erm kaput ) and it has only a I.T.E power supply number.

I can't seem to find where this acronym comes from. Also I wonder if there is a guide to the types of output socket connectors there are as I can't seem to find one that looks the same as mine ( 4 pin male output socket ).

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I.T.E. stands for Information Technology Equipment

There are certain standards, such as in the EU, specifically for ITE that dictate tolerances for electromagnetic radiation etc.

Comment: it seems so untrue in this day and time but this is exactly what it is :) I.T Equipment. Classic. Thanks :)